# zip Files in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below code.Basically with the below code i am trying to grab files from a folder in C:\ and then move them to D:\ and zip them by appending with date. i am getting error at "string outputfilename = Path.Combine..." and i also want to delete the older archived files from the folder.. please can any one guide me.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace test1
{
   class Program
   {
      string folder = @"C:\folder1";
      string folder2 = @"D:\Test1";
      string outputFilename = Path.Combine(output, string.Format(Archive{0}.zip"),DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy"));      
      using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
      {
         foreach (var file Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder))
         zip.Save(outputFilename)
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Please fix your pasted code (missing quotes as you can see from SO code formatter). Please provide error you are getting and specify if it is compile or run time error.

Comment: error i am getting is "System.FormatException was unhandled and it says message=Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list"

Comment: Have you seen whatever you have in the question? The code there have no chance to compile - it is not possible to reason why you are getting runtime errors... And from exception it is not related to Zip-ing files at all...

Comment: i know i got that one..i was missing a parenthesis..

Comment: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ makes dealing with zip files in .net painless.

Comment: Please click "edit" button and fix your code so it looks valid C# code (matching quotes, no undefined variables, no missing semicolons, preferable correct tabs after foreach). Add exception/error you are getting into the question, not in comments (and please try to paste it exactly instead of commonly done "error looks like this ....").

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"c:\users\exampleuser\release.zip", FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry("Readme.txt");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
                    {
                            writer.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
                            writer.WriteLine("========================");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Took from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: but with Filestream i can read a single file..but i want to grab more than one file..

Comment: @radhikarao-You can use this if you do not want to use 3rd party tools http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.100%29

Answer (score 0):

I have used SharpZipLib before and there are a lot of samples [here](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx#Create_a_Zip_with_full_control_over_contents_0) to get you started.

Thanks

Comment: without using any 3rd party tools can we do it..i have pasted the code above..could you tell me if possible where i am going wrong..???

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Response.Clear();

        var downloadFileName = string.Format("" + FileName + ".zip");//string.Format("YourDownload-{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + downloadFileName);

        // Zip the contents of the selected files
        using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            // Add the password protection, if specified
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtZIPPassword.Text))
            {
                zip.Password = txtZIPPassword.Text;

                // 'This encryption is weak! Please see 
               // zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes128;
            }

            // Construct the contents of the README.txt file that will be included in this ZIP
            var readMeMessage = string.Format("Your ZIP file {0} contains the following files:{1}{1}", downloadFileName, Environment.NewLine);

            // Add the checked files to the ZIP
            foreach (ListItem li in cblFiles.Items)
                if (li.Selected)
                {
                    // Record the file that was included in readMeMessage
                    readMeMessage += string.Concat("\t* ", li.Text, Environment.NewLine);

                    // Now add the file to the ZIP (use a value of "" as the second parameter to put the files in the "root" folder)
                    zip.AddFile(li.Value, "Your Files");
                }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(chkDocument.Value) && chkDocument.Checked == true)
            {
                zip.AddFile(chkDocument.Value, "Cover Sheet");
                readMeMessage += string.Concat("\t* ", lbldocName.Text.Trim(), Environment.NewLine);
            }
            // Add the README.txt file to the ZIP
            zip.AddEntry("README.txt", readMeMessage, Encoding.ASCII);


            // Send the contents of the ZIP back to the output stream
            //   zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 65536;
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
            // int a=zip.NumberOfSegmentsForMostRecentSave;
            // txtZIPPassword.Text=a.ToString();
        }

        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```